# Llinking a CSS file is not working

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having an issue with linking my style sheet to the `html` section of my website contained within a `.php` file.

I am unsure as to why some elements of the style sheet are not working, for example if I set the `body`'s `background-color` to red it sets that, however if I create a `div.header` element within the CSS file and try and add it to the element in the html file as `<div id='header'>`, it does nothing.

What could be the reason for this? My CSS file and `.php` file are below.

`courses.css`:

```css
h1{
font:bolder;
}

h3{
font-color:red;
}

body{
background-color:white;
}

div.header{
position:fixed;
margin-top: 1ex;
margin-bottom: 1ex;
background-color: red;
}

div.Select_Course{
position:relative;
right:2ex;
top:4ex;
border:solid thin black;
padding: 5ex;
margin-bottom:3ex;
height:relative;
}
```

and my `.php` file

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password','dbname');
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        die('Database connection failed');
    }
    //$m->set_charset('utf8');
    $search_course = "
    SELECT title, summary, id
    FROM course
    WHERE title LIKE '%".$_POST['searchBar']."%'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($search_course) or die($mysqli->error);
    $search_result = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='courses.css'>
    <div id='header'>
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

    <?php while($search_result = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <div id='Select_Course'>
        <form name="searchresults" method="post" action="selectedcourse.php">

            <h3><?= $search_result['title'] ?>    <input name="searchforcourse" type="submit" value="View Course" /></h3>
            <input name="Coursenamesearch" type="text" value="<?= $search_result['title'] ?>" hidden/>
        </form>
    <p><?= $search_result['summary'] ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: header div should be under <body> tag.

Comment: How about `div#header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a div.header element in your CSS file, just create an element called .header. Then have your HTML like this: .

For example:

CSS file:

```
.header {
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. what does the `div.` create within the css file as this is how ive been shown?

Comment: @bdg Please accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the delay in accepting the answer Thanks again

Comment: @bdg No problem! Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 4):

The div #header must be inside `<body>` not inside `<head>` that tag is only for resources.

And for the problem in your CSS. If you want to reference an element by id you should use `#` instead of `.` that is used only to reference by a class name

Answer (score 0):

A header tag might be ok too

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='courses.css'>
</head>

<header>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header h1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

or just

```
h1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```